# Change what browser glassfish applications deploy to

Tags: jsp, netbeans, browser

In NetBeans 8.1 I have gone to tools > options > general tab and set the default browser to chrome. Yet, when I deploy my webapp JSPs open in IE still. I don't want to change my default system browser. How can I make the web app automatically deploy to Chrome ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a specific target browser for a web application in NetBeans:

- Select the project node of the web application in the **Projects** panel, right click and select **Properties** from the popup menu.
- In the list of **Categories** in the **Properties** window select **Run**.
- Select the browser you want to use from the **Browser** drop down list and click **OK**. (I think the default value is *IDE's default browser*.)

Here's a sample screen shot:

[image: webAppBrowser]